# Add and remove data from object class

Tags: json, vb.net, class

I'm just learning how to work with Json files and my goals are:

- Be able to read a Json file
- View the info on a TreeView
- Be able to Modify, Add, and remove items
- Make again the Json File.

For doing this i've learned about Newtonsoft.Json, that helps a lot. I've almost achieved all my goals except being able to add and remove items from my object.

First of all, I load all the Json content to:

```
Dim ImportedTeams as Teams()
```

The code for the class objects are the following:

```
Public Class Teams
    Property drivers As Drivers()
    Property raceNumber As String
    Property CarModel As String
    Property ballastKg As String
    Property restrictor As String
End Class

Public Class Drivers
    Property firstName As String
    Property lastName As String
End Class
```

I have the ImportedTeams with all data filled, from there I get all I need to fill the Treeview, with diferents levels of nodes, etc.  Also, I can modify the info stored in the class, and make the Json again. No problems until this point

My problems starts here, when I want to add a new Team. What I tried is the following:

```
Dim NewTeam As New Teams
Dim NewDriver as New Drivers

With NewDriver
  .firstName = TB_Name.text
  .lastName = TB_LastName.text
End With


With NewTeam 
  .drivers = NewDriver()
  .raceNumber = NUD_RaceNumbre.Value.ToString
  .CarModel = CBB_Car.index
  .ballastKg = TB_Ballast.Text
  .restrictor = TB_Restrictor.Text
End With
    
ImportedTeams.append(NewTeam)
```

This simply wont work. Don't shows up any error, just nothing happens. Also, I don't know how to remove one Team stored in this object.

I also tried to add only a NewTeam, but same problem.

Thanks for your time mates, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of using arrays, I would use a `List(Of Driver)` and `List(Of Team`). You can then just use `Add(new Driver())` and `Add(new Team()` to append new items.
Also i recommend using class names in singular and the properties in plural.

Comment: Thanks! @AlexB. I will try it and also thanks for you recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex B. said, the solution is easy as follows:

```
Public Class Teams
    Property drivers As **List(of Drivers)**
    Property raceNumber As String
    Property CarModel As String
    Property ballastKg As String
    Property restrictor As String
End Class

Public Class Drivers
    Property firstName As String
    Property lastName As String
End Class
```

And:

```
Dim ImportedTeams as **List(of Teams)**
```

Thanks!